# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolverr android.id.content.Context.getContentesolver()' on a nul object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-volley, android-context

I am using Telr SDK in my app while using it shows me context null pointer except as I have used Volley library and wrote some methods in a class which is extended by 'Application' class. It is showing me this error again and again because I have used 'APPController' class extended by 'Application' class and registered  it in Manifest under 'Applicaion' tag. If I do not use 'Appcontroller' class in my projec then Telr gateway run perfectly but I need to use both please help.

**Code :**

**AppController.java :**

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class
        .getSimpleName();
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SERIF", "fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SANS_SERIF", "fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf");

    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}

}
```

**Telr.java:**

```
public void sendMessage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Demo.this, WebviewActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    intent.putExtra(WebviewActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, getMobileRequest());
    intent.putExtra(WebviewActivity.SUCCESS_ACTIVTY_CLASS_NAME, "com.marketplace.activity.SuccessTransationActivity");
    intent.putExtra(WebviewActivity.FAILED_ACTIVTY_CLASS_NAME, "com.marketplace.activity.FailedTransationActivity");
    intent.putExtra(WebviewActivity.IS_SECURITY_ENABLED, isSecurityEnabled);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I am getting error on :   Intent intent = new Intent(Demo.this, WebviewActivity.class);

**Manifest.xml:**

```
 <application
    android:name="com.marketplace.utils.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon_rect"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon_circle"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme, android:name"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still having this problem, you can fix this problem by creating an Application class if you don't have one already then extend your app class with **Telr Application**, that's it, it will solve your problem.

```
public class MyApp extends TelrApplication {
  public void onCreate(){
      super.onCreate();
   }
  }
}
```